# Why is this variable considered local?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code:

```
with open("01-1-input.txt", "r") as f:
inputs = [int(i[:-2] if i[-1] == "n" else i) for i in f.readlines()]

total_mass = 0

def calculate_fuel_for_mass(mass):
    fuel_for_mass = mass // 3 - 2
    if fuel_for_mass > 0:
        total_mass += fuel_for_mass
        calculate_fuel_for_mass(fuel_for_mass)
    else:
        return 0

for i in inputs:
    calculate_fuel_for_mass(i)

print(total_mass)
```

And it's throwing an `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'total_mass' referenced before assignment`.

Why is that?  I thought any variable declared in the main scope is global?

Comment: A name is considered local if there is any assignment to it in the scope. In your case the `+=`.

Comment: (Remember there is no distinction between declaring and assigning in Python!) I'd recommend having a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
total_mass += fuel_for_mass
```

can be thought of as equivalent to

```
total_mass = total_mass + fuel_for_mass
```

Given a setup like this, python sees an assignment happening to a variable in local scope (inside the function).

A minimal demonstration of this behaviour can be seen as follows:

```
var = 42
def f():
    var = var + 1
#    var += 1 would also show the same behaviour

f() #UnboundLocalError: local variable 'var' referenced before assignment
```

Python infers that there is a local variable total_mass because it sees an assignment to the variable in the local scope.
However, the local variable total_mass has not been assigned a value,
and so you see the error as shown.

You can use the `global` keyword before the assignment to access the variable in the global scope as follows

```
var = 42
def f():
    global var
    var = var + 1

f() #var is now 43 in global scope
```

Comment: Why use `global` here? There's nothing asynchronous going on like e.g. a GUI so just pass `var` as a function argument. Simple and easy to read.

Comment: Im not addressing argument passing or just creating a function in the local scope, as that is not what the question pertains to. The code above is only meant as a demonstration of how to access the variable in the *global* scope, and passing an argument would defeat that purpose. This answer isn't meant to be a demonstration of best practices, just clarification of behaviour as asked by OP.

Comment: Having said that, your recommendation is good for "what one should actually be doing" @MrFuppes

Comment: Good point, passing as an argument is slightly out of the scope of the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of your function, put

```
global total_mass
```

Comment: how is that supposed to answer the question about the "why"?

Comment: Yeah, that's how I fixed it, I just wanna know why is the variable considered local.

Comment: @Capyryan: the point is *variable assignment*, check the comments below your question. To *fix* the error, I'd suggest to pass the respective variable(s) as function argument(s) instead. Using `global` here just makes the code hard to read (imho).

Comment: @MrFuppes Yeah, that's my first attempt at writing recursion, (I never needed it before) and after a bit of thinking I figured out how to do it without any globals.

Comment: Really? How so?

Answer (score -1):

For this, you have to know how variable scopes and mutable/immutable types in Python work. The `int` type is immutable, so when you try to "modify" it in the function, you essentially create a new variable with local scope. As the compiler can see that the variable is going to be local to the function, it assumes that you want to access the local variable in the first place, rather than the global one. It is possible to declare the variable global using the `global` keyword, however it's considered bad practice, as the program becomes harder to read and to debug.

Comment: Assignment is key here, not mutability. Think of a `list` `l` defined in the outer scope of a function. If you perform an operation on `l` like e.g. `l[0] += 1`, you don't assign a new value to `l`, you change a reference in `l` to another value. So `l` won't be considered local to the function. In contrast, if `a = 1` outside the function and you do `a += 1` inside the function, you call an assignment of a new value to `a`, namely the previous value incremented by one.

Comment: I see, apparently my explanation was imprecise. What I meant was that you need to know about mutability to understand what's going on. For example, lists are mutable, this is why they can be modified in a function, which is not possible e.g. with strings. I believe, this can be confusing to newcomers.

Comment: Right, it's good to mention that calling methods on mutable objects (like `__setitem__` in my comment above) is possible in this context since it is not an assignment. Still, variable scope /wrt the question is defined by assignment.